# How to embed python into a kotlin/java Android app?

Tags: python, android, windows, bundle, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have an Android app written in kotlin that needs to call python code. I would like the app to come bundled with the necessary python binaries to execute some python scripts as well as the required python libraries, ideally managed by pip in a virtual environment.

I already have some code that will copy these files from the assets folder that is bundled into the APK when building the app, but I don't know where to find recent python binaries that can run natively on Android. I'm assuming I need something like a arm64 version of python >3.7 .

A second issue I have is that I'm developing the app on Windows, so the virtual environment and some dependencies are not cross platform. I would probably need a way to either automatically convert the windows virtualenv into a valid project structure with correct dependencies, or a way to create and manage a linux virtual environment from Windows (maybe WSL can save me here).

What is the preferred method? Are there open source Android apps that have solved similar issues?

Comment: Very interesting. Check out the Jython project: https://www.jython.org/ Good luck!

Comment: See https://wiki.python.org/moin/Android .

Comment: Take a look on https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/, I am going to explore it now for my own aims. Regarding OS development issue, consider to install Virtual Machine to run Linux you are interested in development - it will allow you to combine your WIndows dependent needs with your needs in Linux.